# compiling Hunspell dictionary

Tags: hunspell

If at the end of the word there are two identical letters (kk, pp, tt), then the word is inclined in one way, and if the last two letters are different, then in another way.
**How can this be taken into account within one group (flag)?**

SFX m Y 6
SFX m 0 ma
SFX m kk km
SFX m pp pma
SFX m ss sma
SFX m tt tma
SFX m xx xma

That is, the word is given in the nominative case. For example: *zapt*. In the case, it should be zaptma (ma is added at the end).
But if a word is inflected, at the end of which there are two identical characters (kk, pp, tt, ss, xx), for example - *zapp*, then this word is inflected *zapma* (not *zappma* !!).